Sin & punishment (or consequence)
חג שמח לכולם
I missed the exact quote, though I already read some hebrew motto which states in a short phrase that when someone sins, the Divine reward (punishment or consequence) for the sin is directly related to the sin.
Do you know the motto and the textual reference? Thank you very much.

Mida Keneged Mida, "measure corresponding to measure." Appears all over the Talmud and Midrash.

@Shalom "Mida Keneged Mida, 'measure corresponding to measure.' Appears all over the Talmud and Midrash." Indeed!
